# 'Unresolved Dependencies' after reinstalling Grails

Tags: plugins, grails, groovy

New clone from git repo, fresh install of groovy and grails. Seems to work for everyone else on my team? New to groovy and grails. Any help or general troubleshooting is appreciated.

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.grails.plugins#dynamic-jasper;0.6: not found

:: org.grails.plugins#testing;0.5: not found

:: org.grails.plugins#code-coverage;1.1.8: not found

:: org.grails.plugins#liquibase;1.9.3.3: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 3):

You may just need to do a `grails clean` - have you tried that?

Grails stores its plugins in `~/.grails`; if all else fails, it might not hurt to go in and clean out that directory after doing a fresh install.

Comment: I have the same problem.  If I try "grails clean", i get the same error messages.  I tried deleting my windows user/.grails dir but get the same error.